# using std::variant with a vector

Tags: c++, vector, variant

I'm writing a program that uses a variant in a vector and I encoutred a problem saying:

```
E0413   no suitable conversion function from "std::variant<char, short>" to "char" exists
```

this is my program:

```
int main()
{
   
   std::vector<std::variant<char, short>> vec;
   switch(type)
   {
     case 1200: //char
       char tab[10];
       for(unsigned i = 0; i<6; i++)
           tab[i] = vec.at(i);
     case 1300: //short
       short tab[10];
       for(unsigned i = 0; i<6; i++)
           tab[i] = vec.at(i);
   }
 return 0;
}
```

I used `std::variant` because type distinction is needed.

how could I solve this?

thank you

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: Please share a [MCVE]. The code shown is incomplete, and does not produce the error you are asking about.

Comment: sorry, I edited the post

Comment: `tab = vec.at(i);` makes no sense. Not only because of the conversion problem but also because `vec[i]` is a single value and `tab` is an array.

Answer (score 6):

```
       char tab[10];
       for(unsigned i = 0; i<6; i++)
           tab[i] = vec.at(i);
```

You need to explicitly specify which type of the variant you want to take. For this, you can use [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get):

```
       char tab[10];
       for(unsigned i = 0; i<6; i++)
           tab[i] = std::get<char>(vec.at(i)); // std::get<0>(vec.at(i)) would have the same effect
```

Comment: if I'm using something like that ```decltype(m->skinning.realWeights)::value_type```, how can I handle it?

Comment: @Lou do you mean you're trying to use `value_type` to determine whether to take a `char` or a `short`? It would be nice if you could add this to the question so the intent is made clearer, and it's easier to provide a solution.

Comment: no, I mean the ```value_type``` won't be deduced since ```realWeights``` is the name of my vector, I have to do something like ```std::get<short>``` ?

Comment: ```decltype(std::get<short>(m->skinning.realWeights))::value_type```? ```decltype``` will deduce ```std::variant```

Comment: @Lou I'm not sure if I understand your example. if `realWeights` is a vector, you're not meant to use `std::get` on it, you're supposed to use it on a variant. And `decltype` with a short value should return a `short` (or `short` with some reference), and `short`s don't have any `value_type` member. It would be nice if you could update your question slightly, because I'm still a bit unclear.

Comment: ah no, ```realWeights``` is a vector of variant. it's like what I put on the post with some name changes

Comment: @Lou you would still have to index the vector (with `[]` or `at`) to get some variant out of it, with which you call `std::get`. And the other issue still remains. `decltype(std::get<short>(some_variant))` will be a `short`, and a `short` has no `value_type` member.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::get<char>(variant)` instead of implicit conversion.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get

Comment: can you explain more, I can't see how to use it

Comment: If you need a `char`, use `std::get<char>(v)`. If you need a short, use `std::get<short>(v)`. If the type is bad it will throw an exception.

Comment: I have vector of variant, this is different from the example you showed me